# Is it possible to execute shell with parameterized remote ip?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a job like this:

1. parameterized ${GIT_URL} and ${REMOTE_IP}.
2. clone code by git url and package my project as jar
3. scp jar file to remote ip, and then start it as server.`
4. I am using [Publish Over SSH Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin).

The problem is, I have to add every server to my job configuration.

So is it possible to execute shell with parameterized remote ip like this?

```
    #!/bin/sh
    scp ${APP_NAME}.jar root@${REMOTE_IP}:/root/${APP_NAME}.jar
    ssh root@${REMOTE_IP}
    cd /root
    ps -ef | grep ${APP_NAME} | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
    nohup java -jar ${APP_NAME}.jar &
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this in another way.

```
#!/bin/sh
scp ${APP_NAME}.jar root@${REMOTE_IP}:/root/${APP_NAME}.jar
ssh root@${REMOTE_IP} "sh -s" -- < /opt/jenkins/my.sh ${REMOTE_IP} ${APP_NAME}
```

So my.sh is a local shell file which define how to start jar as server with parameterized ip

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use "$REMOTE_IP" to resolve it to the parameter value.

```
#!/bin/sh
scp ${APP_NAME}.jar root@"$REMOTE_IP":/root/${APP_NAME}.jar
ssh root@"$REMOTE_IP"
cd /root
ps -ef | grep ${APP_NAME} | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
nohup java -jar ${APP_NAME}.jar &
```

Comment: Have you ever tried this?I don't think it does work.

Comment: In my opinion, jenkins do not pass the stdin to remote ip after ssh. So do you mean use `"$REMOTE_IP"` instead of `${REMOTE}` solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry no I didnt test this using over SSH. Just passing parameter value to a shell script in the same job